# Is it enough if i use one typedef struct?

Tags: c, struct, types, stack

I am writing a C program where I will use stack. My program will read the data from a file. I am asked to use typedef struct. Can I use typedef once just for stack? or should I hafve different 2 typedef struct like this:

```
typedef struct 
{    
  int age;
  float money;
  char  id[15];
} data;

typedef struct 
{
  float* data;
  int member ;
}stack;
```

Comment: What does the second typedef mean?! That is what do these declarations float* data;
int ; mean?

Comment: Pro tip: try to pick a better naming convention. Either 1) don't use typedef at all (use `struct data` everywhere, so that everyone knows that `struct data` is a type), or 2) use a `_t` suffix (so that `data_t` is a type, and `data` is a field/variable) -- not strictly "posix compliant", but it's a fairly common convention and clearly expresses the intention, or 3) use pascal casing or whatever other casing for type names (so that `Data` is a type and `data` is a field or a variable). My company sticks to the 2nd approach (`typedef struct { ... } data_t`), but pick whatever works best.

Answer (score 0):

`typedef` keyword is used to assign a new name to a type.
We can also use typedef to assign a new name to structure which is a user-defined datatype as follows:

```
   typedef struct structure_name
   {
       data-type member-1;
       data-type member-2;
       data-type member-3;
       data-type member-4;
    }type_name;
```

Now, while declaring variables of this structure type, we can write `type_name` in place of `struct structure_name` in the whole program.

> Can I use typedef once just for stack? or should I hafve different 2
> typedef struct like this:

You have to use `typedef`  for every structure, if you want to use just the `type_name` instead of `struct structure_name`.

Example : If we donot use `typedef` , then to create an instance of the structure , we need to use `struct structure_name struct_instance`.
If we use `typedef`  , then we can just use `typename struct_instance`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil  I mean, if  we want to avoid the usage of `struct struct_name` format

Comment: @EricPostpischil  Modified the answer. I agree my statement is misleading

Answer (score 0):

For starters this declaration

```
typedef struct 
{
float* data;
int ;
}stack;
```

is invalid and in any case does not make a sense.

What you need is to define two structures. The first structure will declare a node of the stack as for example

```
typedef struct Node 
{    
    int age;
    float money;
    char  id[15];
    struct Node *next;
} Node;
```

The second structure will declare the stack itself as for example

```
typedef struct Stack
{
    struct Node *top;
} Stack;
```

And in main you can declare an object of the type Stack like

```
Stack stack = { NULL };
```

The function that pushes new elements on the stack can be declared like

```
int push( Stack *stack, int age, float money, const char *id );
```

Comment: `stack` structure declaration might be a typing mistake. I edited it for approval.